# Conditional formatting based on date

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

**Trying to set up a time card at work in Excel, have dates going down the left-hand side of the worksheet:**

Fri 1/1/11

Sat 1/2/11

Sun 1/3/11

**And so on. I want to gray out the rows with weekend dates like so:**

Fri 1/1/11

```
Sat 1/2/11
Sun 1/3/11
```

**Is there an obvious way to do this using conditional formatting?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel 2010 - Conditional Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680983/excel-2010-conditional-formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use the `WEEKDAY` function to determine the day of the week, like this:

```
=WEEKDAY($A1,2)>5
```

Depending on what days of the week are considered the weekend, you may need to modify the second parameter.  You can find more information about the `WEEKDAY` function (and the second parameter) [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/weekday-function-HP010343015.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming dates are in Column A:

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY($A1)=1,WEEKDAY($A1)=7),1,0)
```

Reads If the weekday is either Sunday or Saturday then True (Use Conditional Formatting)

Or you can modify the same formula so that the 'weekdays' starts on Monday so it looks like this:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY($A1,2)>5,1,0)
```

Comment: cool, thanks. had to change it to 

   =IF(OR(WEEKDAY($A1)=6,WEEKDAY($A1)=5),1,0)

to get it to work, but this did the trick.

Comment: won't that gray out Thursday and Friday? Within conditional formatting you don't really need to return 1 or 0 with an IF function, you only need an expression that returns TRUE or FALSE like LittleBobbyTables suggestion

Comment: @barryhoudini I agree with you regarding that it may be unnecessary to wrap inside of an IF. In this case it's almost like saying: if the test is true, then return true, if the test is false then return false... I'm just used to wrapping my conditional statements like this because I usually wrote more advanced formulas so it was a matter of habit.

Comment: And yeah I'm confused why that worked for him too because it is set for thursday/ friday.
Danger here is that the conditional formatting was implemented in cells expecting to be based on their own values but are actually being based on adjecent cells values by mistake.

It's a common mistake for users new to using formula sin conditional formatting to have initial trouble lining up the cell reference with the formula to achieve the desired effects.

so @barryhoudini be sure that you test that conditional formatting!