# Conditional format of date where 3 working days greater than cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I am trying to adapt a number of forum posts and previous stack questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400471/conditional-formatting-based-on-date).

Let's say I have a date Column `A2, A3, A4 etc`.

I want to be able to utilize the `WEEKDAY` function to evaluate my condition when only in a `Weekday` and also `3 days greater than the date` in `Cell A(x)`.

So far my attempts have failed or I have not got the results I want.  Excel is not my strongest point when it comes to conditional formula formatting.

I think it may be something like:

```
=WEEKDAY(A$2,2) <=5 AND 'My Cell Date' > 3 Days WHERE those 3 days are weekdays.
```

Also if it is possible, I want it to work like:

`If day 1 of 3 is Thursday, day 2 of 3 is Friday and day 3 of 3 is Monday then apply formatting`.

Could anyone help me out with this one please?

*Edit not from OP* to copy clarification from comments:

- If the today date is 3 working days greater than the cell date change to red.
- Say A2 has a received date and B2 has a completed date. The completed date is my target. Is it 3 working days greater than received.

Comment: Basically if this evaluates as true then I want to set the colour of the cell.  Thanks for taking the time the comment.  If the today date is 3 working days greater than the cell date change to red

Comment: Ok, lets say A2 has a received date and B2 has a completed date.  The completed date is my target.  Is it 3 working days greater than received.  I was trying to keep as simple as possible.  Sorry if not clear.

Comment: Clearly missed that one.  Please submit answer and you can have it.  I must have been having a moment or something.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was not quite certain of the requirement (but seem to have hit upon an acceptable solution!):

Use `=NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2)>2` under Format values where this formula is true: under Use a formula to determine which cells to format in Conditional Formatting.

[NETWORKDAYS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/networkdays-HP005209190.aspx)

> Returns the number of whole working days between start_date and end_date. Working days exclude weekends and any dates identified in holidays.

The syntax is:

**NETWORKDAYS(start_date,end_date**,holidays)

> Dates should be entered by using the DATE function, or as results of other formulas or functions.